# FileVault2 command line commands in Mojave?

Tags: command-line, mojave, filevault

I've been reading about using the `fdsetup` command to manage FileVault2 from the command line. But I can't find it in Mojave (or High Sierra for that matter).

Is there a command line interface to FileVault2?

Comment: What do you mean with "can't find it"? Do you get an error when running it from the command line?

Comment: @nohillside, gctwnl probably means when running `fdsetup` it returns `-bash: fdsetup: command not found` as the actual command name is `fdesetup ` not `fdsetup`. Note in the OP the command is missing an `e`.

Comment: @user3439894, yes that was what I meant. See comment under the answer below for what I ended up using.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The *command* you want is: `fdesetup`

From its manual page:

> fdesetup(8)                    BSD System Manager's Manual
>
> NAME
>           **fdesetup** -- FileVault configuration tool
>
> SYNOPSIS
>           **fdesetup** verb [options]
>
> DESCRIPTION
>           **fdesetup** is used to enable or disable FileVault, to list, add, or remove
>        enabled FileVault users, and to obtain status about the current state of
>        FileVault. Most commands require root access and need to be authenticated
>        with either a FileVault password, a personal recovery key (if enabled),
>        and in some cases the private key from the installed institutional recov-
>        ery key.  Some status related commands can be run from a non-root session.

Comment: Yep, it was that simple, I had misread. In the end, I used `sysadminctl` (no man page, type `sysadminctl -help`) to manage SecureTokens (which is what I needed to do). Probably not meant to be used directly, but it did what I needed.

Answer (score -1):

```
fdesetup help
  Sets up FileVault for the current boot volume.
  Usage: fdesetup <verb> <options>
  Use the man page for expanded help.
  Verbs:
      help
      enable            Enable FileVault and optionally add user(s)
      disable           Disable FileVault
      status            Return current FileVault status
      add               Add user(s) to existing FileVault
      remove            Remove user from FileVault
      list              List users or locked volumes
      changerecovery    Change or add recovery key
      removerecovery    Remove recovery key
      sync              Synchronize existing FileVault user information
      haspersonalrecoverykey            Checks to see if a personal recovery key has been set
      hasinstitutionalrecoverykey       Checks to see if a institutional recovery key has been set
      usingrecoverykey                  Checks to see if a recovery key is currently in use
      supportsauthrestart               Displays 'true' if the system supports the authenticated restart option
      authrestart                       On supported systems, restarts computer and unlocks FileVault one time
      validaterecovery                  Checks to see if the recovery key is valid
      isactive                          Displays 'true' if the volume is encrypted.
      showdeferralinfo                  Displays any deferral configuration information.
      version
  Options:
      -certificate <certificate path> Path to a DER encoded certificate file to use during enabling.
      -defer <filepath> Defer enabling FileVault.
      -device <bsd, mount path, or locked LVF UUID> FV context information location.
      -dontaskatlogout When defering enablement, don't prompt at user logout.
      -extended Show extended information.
      -forceatlogin <bypassValue> When defering enablement, force user to enable at login after n times (0=next time, 9999=only request, not force).
      -forcerestart Force a restart without confirmation immediately after successfully enabling FileVault
      -inputplist Reads configuration info from stdin.
      -institutional Option to specify an institutional recovery key.
      -key <keychain path> Path to the authentication keychain private key file.
      -keychain Use the FileVaultMaster.keychain to add an institutional recovery key when enabling FileVault.
      -norecoverykey Do not return a recovery key when enabling FileVault.
      -offline Displays offline, locked volumes.
      -outputplist Outputs key and computer info to stdout.
      -personal Option to specify a personal recovery key.
      -prompt Always prompt for authentication information.   Does not work when using -key
      -quiet No status during enable.
      -user <username> Short user name.
      -usertoadd <username> Additional user name when enabling or adding users.
      -uuid <uuid> User UUID.
      -delayminutes <minutes> Number of minutes before restart.
      -verbose Enable verbose mode.
```